# Android translated canvas collision of rectangles

Tags: java, android, canvas, collision, game-physics

im trying do develop a Zelda like game. So far i am using bitmaps and everything runs smooth. At this point the camera of the hero is fixed, meaning, that he can be anywhere on the screen.

The problem with that is scaling. Supporting every device and keeping every in perfect sized rects doesnt seem to be that easy :D
To prevent that i need a moving camera. Than i can scale everything to be equally sized on every device. The hero would than be in the middle of the screen for the first step.

The working solution for that is

```
xCam += hero.moveX;
yCam += hero.moveY;
canvas.translate(xCam,yCam);
drawRoom();
canvas.restore();
drawHero();
```

I do it like this, because i dont wand to rearrange every tile in the game. I guess that could be too much processing on some devices. As i said, this works just fine. the hero is in the middle of the screen, and the whole room is moving.
But the problem is collision detection.
Here a quick example:

```
wall.rect.intersects(hero.rect);
```

Assuming the wall was originally on (0/0) and the hero is on (screenWitdh/2 / screenHeight/2) they should collide on some point.
The problem is, that the x and y of the wall.rect never change. They are (0/0) at any point of the canvas translation, so they can never collide.

I know, that I can work with canvas.getClipBounds() and then use the coordinates of the returned rect to change every tile, but as I mentioned above, I am trying to avoid that plus, the returned rect only works with int values, and not float.

Do you guys know any solution for that problem, or has anyone ever fixed something like this?

Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your model logic and view logic. Suppose your development dimension for the window is WxH. In this case if your sprite in the model is 100x100 and placed at 0,0, it will cover area from 0,0 to 100, 100. Let's add next sprite (same 100x100 dimension) at 105,0 (basically slightly to the right of the first one), which covers area from 105,0 to 205,100. It is obvious that in the model they are not colliding. Now, as for view if your target device happens to be WxH you just draw the model as it is. If your device has a screen with w = 2*W, h = 2*H, so twice as big in each direction. You just multiply `the x and y by w / W and h / H` respectively. Therefore we get 2x for x and y, which on screen becomes 1st object - from 0,0 to 200, 200, 2nd object - from 210,0 to 410, 200. As can be seen they are still not colliding. To sum up, separate your game logic from your drawing (rendering) logic.

Comment: But thats not my problem.

My problem is, that i need to detect the collison on a translated canvas. The hero position ist the same at all times - half the screen width/height.

But i need the position of the wall. If it was 0/0 before the canvas translate, why is it 0/0 if the canvas is translated? Shouldnt the x and y of the wall change?

Comment: Apologies, I may have misunderstood the question. After translation, can you not obtain translated values for objects (wall)? After doing that it's just a matter of checking collision between 2 bounding boxes

Comment: No problem :D
Well thats the problem... the box of the hero is always half the screen x/y. In my opinion that seems right, because well... he is in the middle of the screen at all times.

But i dont get why the x and y of the wall keep being at 0/0. With the logic behind the translation, it seems kinda correct. But i cant find a way to retreive the ne x and y !WITHOUT! calculation it again for every tile with the value of the translation. My fear is that, is slows down the performance really badly if i have to recalculate the position of everything in every frame

Comment: Optimisations must always be done with a profiling tool and at the end of development with a few exceptional cases. As for solution, like http://stackoverflow.com/users/2169868/mad-manny said, you keep track of the player's position in the model. If you do not want to recalculate objects' positions, then your player has to move. It's fine if you want to keep him in the middle of the screen. By applying negative translation on the canvas you will achieve what you want

Comment: I already do that... thats the problem. I apply the negative position movement velocity to the canvas translation. 
xCam += hero.moveX;
yCam += hero.moveY;
But with a translated canvas the x and y of the whole canvas changes and not the positions of the walls. That means, if the upper left corner wall is next to the hero (in the middle of the screen) the hitbox of the wall keeps being at total 0/0 (in the original upper left corner). Does that mean, that i have to draw the heros sprite in the middle, but move the hitbox of the hero? that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have variables holding the player's position on the "map". So you can use this to determine the collision with the non changing wall. It should look something like (depensing on the rest of your code):

```
canvas.translate(-hero.rect.centerX(), -.rect.centerY());
drawRoom();
canvas.restore();
drawHero();
```

Generally you should do the calculations in map coordinates, not on screen. For rendering just use the (negative) player position for translation.

Comment: To be clearer. The hero coordinates MUST be the same at any point.
Because the hero should be in the middle of the screen. If he moves, the floor actually does.

I guess that i have to get the new translated positon opf the wall, but they dont change.

Or is my way wrong? Then please enlighten me :D

Comment: As AlmasB considered you should separate your logic and your graphics. So you would move the player on the map and after all calculations bring that on the screen.